# How do I open an anaconda prompt

Tags: ubuntu, anaconda

I have installed Anaconda on my Ubuntu 16.04 operating system. The instructions I was following seemed to think I would have a desktop icon, but I don't. I eventually found out that I needed to type `anaconda-navigator` in my terminal to open it.

I am now trying to open an `anaconda prompt`. The lack of search results on how to do so, leads me to believe that it's very trivial under normal circumstances. But I don't see any icon, and when I look for `anaconda` or `prompt` in my apps, Ubuntu returns nothing.

I have also tried typing `anaconda-prompt` in the terminal, but no joy.

Is there something wrong with my installation or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 3):

When installing to Linux or MacOS, there isn't an anaconda prompt. Everything is set up to use the terminal.

Taken from [the official anaconda website](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/verify-install/) (emphasis is mine):

---

You can also use conda in an Anaconda Prompt (**terminal on Linux or macOS**).

To open Anaconda Prompt (or terminal on Linux or macOS):

- Windows: Open the Anaconda Prompt (Click Start, select Anaconda
  Prompt)
- macOS: Open Launchpad, then open terminal or iTerm.
- **Linux–CentOS: Open Applications - System Tools - terminal.**
- **Linux–Ubuntu: Open the Dash by clicking the upper left Ubuntu icon,
  then type “terminal”.**

---

Answer (score 3):

Now I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and the process I followed is:

1. invoke terminal.
2. type `activate` hit <kbd>enter</kbd>.
3. type `anaconda-navigator` hit <kbd>enter</kbd>.

you should have the anaconda navigator dashboard.

Answer (score 2):

Open terminal and use:

```
conda activate
```

"(base)" should appear in your command line.

More information: [Conda: command not found on macOS or Linux](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/user-guide/troubleshooting/#conda-command-not-found-on-macos-or-linux)

Answer (score 2):

I found a very easy way to solve this problem.
You can type `source ~/anaconda3/bin/activate root` .
Then, you will enter to the (base).

I learnt from this video：
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PoBxbwbrZy0

By the way, I use 22.04 version.

Answer (score 1):

Try a restart. I had the (base) environment activated afterwards, even though I had not changed the shell when the installer asked me to:

```shell
installation finished.
Do you wish to update your shell profile to automatically initialize conda?
This will activate conda on startup and change the command prompt when activated.
If you'd prefer that conda's base environment not be activated on startup,
   run the following command when conda is activated:

conda config --set auto_activate_base false

You can undo this by running `conda init --reverse $SHELL`? [yes|no]
[no] >>> 
You have chosen to not have conda modify your shell scripts at all.
To activate conda's base environment in your current shell session:

eval "$(/root/anaconda3/bin/conda shell.YOUR_SHELL_NAME hook)" 

To install conda's shell functions for easier access, first activate, then:

conda init

Thank you for installing Anaconda3!
```

Reading this, you would think that I would still have to activate the base environment at terminal start since I did not type `yes`, but I did not have to do that, likely since I only updated an Anaconda installation with this step already done. After this update, the terminal always showed the `(base)` in front.

Clearly, if you still need to change your settings, you need:

```
conda config --set auto_activate_base true
```